# About internet. Why Skip 420 in HTTP 4xx Client errors?

Tags: http, https, client-server, http-status-codes

He guys, I am learning HTTPS and HTTP requests and come across a list of [HTTP_status_codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) on Wiki.

4xx Client errors start at 400 and increment 1 at a time all the way up to 418 (I'm a teapot- april fools joke in 1998) then it skipped 419 and 420? then the error codes become continuous again for a little while then we seeing large gaps between numbers. (like 431 and 451)

**Now, I don't care too much about 419 but why skip 420** while all previous error codes are continuous? I am a curious bunny and I been searching all morning but can't seem to find out. Is there a logical reason behind this unfair skip or just because of the stigma tie to 420?

I know some of these error codes were introduced back in 1980? 90? (correct me if I am wrong please) I am trying to know the history behind it but can't seem to find it. like this Quora Post [What is the history behind Microsoft HTTP status codes?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-is-the-history-behind-Microsoft-HTTP-status-codes) asked in Mar 26, 2015 with 2000+ views but no one has answered it yet.....I am going to the library hoping to find something in physical books. I hope someone can shed some light on this in the meantime.

---

update:

I checked out a book call *History of the Internet: A Chronology, 1843 to the Present* by Moschovitis from the public local library. I am gonna start reading it. If you have already read this book and this is not going to help me then please leave a comment.

I also emailed some of my old CS professors from college. I think most of them are on winter break but I will post updates once I hear back from them.

Comment: As far as I recall, HTTP/2 used 421, not 420, because of Twitter's (unregistered) use of 420.

Comment: is that the reason? but Twitter was launched in 2006. I think that is a while after HTTP 4xx client error got introduced.

Comment: 421 was introduced in HTTP/2, only a few years ago.